# WebBrowser problema para clicar em elementos do site

Tags: c#, vb.net, navegador-de-internet

Olá, pessoal!
Preciso acessar esse link: https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140809134831AAoevh8

Utilizando o IE, Chrome, Firefox... qualquer navegador eu consigo normalmente sem nenhum erro, mas ao tentar acessar esse link pelo Webbrowser o site simplesmente fica bugado.

1)
Vou explicar melhor: Lá em baixo da página existe uma área para comentários.
Uma foto para melhor compreensão: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pQ2s.png

2)
Quando eu clico nesse textarea para comentar, rapidamente em qualquer navegador o componente se alonga. 
Uma foto para melhor compreensão: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpyWU.png

No entanto, ao acessar esse mesmo link utilizando o Webbrowser, ao clicar no textarea dos comentários, nada acontece.
O elemento da página permanece na posição inicial, como se eu nem tivesse clicado...

Alguém pode me dar uma luz do que está acontecendo e como posso resolver esse problema?

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: acontece o erro de script ao tentar abrir a página ? http://i.stack.imgur.com/UEOq1.png

Comment: Wesley, acredito que está à adicionar um WebBrowser em uma aplicação Desktop, possivelmente WebForms ou WPF.
Em todo caso, aconselho você usar o CefSharp (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) para extender a capacidade do WebBrowser, desta forma ele vai usar `Chromium Embedded Framework` ao invés de uma versão embarcada e antiga do IE (que não deve saber o que é HTML5, CC3 ou ECMAScript 5).

Comment: Sim, Thiago Falcão!
Acontecem diversos erros de script
Uma foto: http://i.imgur.com/t2pI6QS.png

Comment: Olá, TobyMosque!
Dei uma olhada no CefSharp aqui. Acho que essa pode ser a solução... mudar a engine do navegador, mas eu queria saber o porquê do erro mesmo sabe, se existe algum jeito de resolver porque eu gosto muito do Webbrowser do Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estou fazendo um navegador avançado e editei muita coisa nele para remover erros de script e renderizar melhor a página, mas vou compartilhar uma parte do meu código para ver se pode lhe ajudar.

```vb
'Coloque isso no método iniciador da forma principal (Form1)
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(Function() True)
```

OK, daí ele irá ignorar erros de certificado, mas isso não irá fazer sentido agora, coloque essa linha, **tem que ser a primeira expressão** do evento `Load` do seu `WebBrowser`:

```vb
 'Ao carregar seu Webbrowser (WebBrowser1.Load):
 WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
```

Beleza, de padrão o WebBrowser é renderizado pelo renderizador do **Internet Explorer 7** (infelizmente), porém felizmente **podemos colocar para a versão mais alta, no caso o IE 11**.

Essa parte é o que mais vai fazer diferença, coloque esse código no arquivo **Application.Designer.vb**

> Localizado no diretório do seu projeto, vai na pasta **My Project** e o arquivo irá estar lá.

Coloque esse método `Namespace My.MyApplication`:

```vb
  Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
     CreateBrowserKey()
  End Sub

  Private Sub MyApplication_Shutdown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shutdown
     ' Se quiser que remova a propriedade:
     ' RemoveBrowerKey()
  End Sub

  Private Const BrowserKeyPath As String = "\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION"

  Private Sub CreateBrowserKey(Optional ByVal IgnoreIDocDirective As Boolean = False)
     Dim basekey As String = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.ToString
     Dim value As Int32
     Dim thisAppsName As String = My.Application.Info.AssemblyName & ".exe"

     ' Value reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
     ' IDOC Reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
     Select Case (New WebBrowser).Version.Major
        Case 8 'Internet Explorer 8
           If IgnoreIDocDirective Then
              value = 8888
           Else
              value = 8000
           End If

        Case 9 'IE 9
           If IgnoreIDocDirective Then
              value = 9999
           Else
              value = 9000
           End If
        Case 10 'IE 10
           If IgnoreIDocDirective Then
              value = 10001
           Else
              value = 10000
           End If

        Case 11 'IE 11
           If IgnoreIDocDirective Then
              value = 11001
           Else
              value = 11000
           End If

        Case Else ' não achou o ie?!
           Exit Sub

     End Select

     Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.ToString & BrowserKeyPath,
                                       Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName & ".exe",
                                       value,
                                       Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)
  End Sub

  Private Sub RemoveBrowerKey()
     Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
     key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(BrowserKeyPath.Substring(1), True)
     key.DeleteValue(Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName & ".exe", False)
  End Sub
```

Tenta fazer isso, abraços!

> **Dica:** Se não achar o arquivo, coloque esses métodos na Form1.

Comment: Olá, CypherPotato!
Cara funcionou!!! Essa ideia de alterar a versão do IE é realmente muito boa! Obrigado, me salvou ;)

Só me surgiu uma dúvida, o requisito então para um usuário utilizar o programa sem problemas é ter uma versão do IE entre 8 e 11 instalada na máquina, certo?

Comment: Essa `Select Case` irá obter a maior versão do Internet Explorer instalado no computador, se o usuário tiver o 11, irá renderizar o site como o 11, de tiver o 10, irá renderizar com o 10, e assim por diante...